# String explosion when using Dict(zip(fieldnames, data)) function and csv.DictWriter

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, zip

I am trying to  get the following code to run, but I continually get "dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 's', 't', 'd', 'e', 'v'."

```
def csv_dict_writer(loc, fieldNames, data):

    with open(loc, "w", newline='') as out_file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, delimiter = ',', fieldnames=fieldNames, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        writer.writeheader()
        print(loc,fieldNames,data)
        for row in data: writer.writerow(row)

setAndSpike = ['diff', 'min', 'max', 'mode', 'mean', 'stdev', 'var'];
datSet = [2.88, 21.78, 24.67, 22.04, 23.06, 0.92, 0.85];
second = dict(zip(setAndSpike,datSet));
csv_dict_writer(filePath + 'textFirst.csv', setAndSpike, second)
```

I have performed a search for a similar topic, and they've all turned up different answers--use quoting in csv module, don't use writerows in DictWriter module, making my keys a tuple, lining up the data sets--but the keys keep coming out as strings that have exploded.

Oddly, when I attempt this just with `dict(zip(setAndSpike,datSet))` it seems to align fine.

I am looking for any help at all, even a direction to this topic if it's been previously answered. I cannot find a similar issue as solved, and it seems something rather simple.

I am running the code in Spyder2, through Anaconda3, and Python 3.4. I may come across as a  new user and that's because I am.

Thanks in advance for your patience and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
csv_dict_writer(filePath + 'textFirst.csv', setAndSpike, second)
```

It looks like `csv_dict_writer`'s third parameter is supposed to be a list of dicts, but you're only passing in a single dict. Try wrapping it in a list.

```
csv_dict_writer(filePath + 'textFirst.csv', setAndSpike, [second])
```